# Access signal strength per user from Wi-Fi router

Tags: wireless-router

I’m trying to find a way to access the signal strength per user connected to a Wi-Fi router. Do I need to have specific equipment or can I do it with just any router? I’m thinking of getting a [TP-LINK TL-MR3040](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-4691_TL-MR3040.html), due to its WISP functionality. In the end I want to have an Arduino like device get that information from the router.

Answer (score 0):

How you do this will depend on your hardware - and is something you really need to ask your supplier on.  We do not do product recommendations on SU.

That said, if you get a device which runs dd-wrt you can issue a command "wl noise" on the device.  You should, theoretically, be able to script this to work with an Arduino if the arduino can connect to it over telnet or equivalent, or if the device has a serial port which can be controlled as a tty and you can link it to an Arduino.   Are you sure an Arduino is the correct tool for the job ?  (ie are you using these signal strengths to control sensors or outputs ?  Its not my area of expertise, but wouldn't you be better off connecting it to a Raspberry Pi ?)

Comment: I want to calculate the best position of the router based on what the signal of each user is, i.e. lower than average means that the router will have to move closer to that user. That is going to be done with a motorized vehicle controlled by (probably) an Intel Edison platform that runs on Linux. Also to be honest I'm a networks newbie so is it possible to be a bit more elaborate on your previous answer? I only got the telnet acronym.

Comment: Interesting idea - but how are you going to get the signal to the AP from the clients .  It may be more beneficial (and cheaper !) to hook up more access points instead.  Also, you may want to focus more on selecting the quietest channel and possibly use of directional antennas (unless you intend to use MIMO) depending on the number and location of users.

Comment: The question as asked is not amenable to a step-by-step answer in SU - and indeed the idea may benefit from more thought (for example - and I've never used an Edison) - making the Edison act as an AP or using that [ it runs linux so its easy to get the data] to monitor signal strength.

Comment: I know that adding APs would be easier, there are solutions for that, what I'm trying to do is more of a proof of concept. I'm not interested to have Edison as an AP, as I don't care if it has network connection. I don't want to remote control the unit or to access it over the net. I only need to know how to access that "table" (if possible at all) so that it will run them through a path finding algorithm to decide where to go next. The form of the data is not really important, it can be through the AP's interface or anything, I can make a parser for it, where from is the question.